Unable to type Greek Polytonic on my Texmaker in raspberry pi 5 (Wayland, Bookworm)
I was able to type Greek Polytonic in TexMaker to produce a pdfLatex on a Raspberry, now I cannot. I guess it may be with how  Raspberry 5 / Wayland recognizes my Jelly Comb keyboard, (like iOS?) as it has changed the position of other characters too: the backslash is now where the # used to be.
However, the Raspberry types correctly anywhere else than in Texmaker. On the other hand Texmaker can display accented characters if I copy/paste them in a document. I just cannot type them myself.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
ξαφνικα δεν μπορω να βαλω τονους στο εγγραφο. Το νεο μου \foreignlanguage{english}{raspberry/raspbian/debian} φαινεται να αναγνωριζει διαφορετικα το πληκτρολογιο \foreignlanguage{english}{Jelly Comb} (π.χ. το \textbackslash \ εχει παει αλλου απ οτι ητανε πριν). Αν αντιγραψω κειμενο το παρουσιαζει σωστα:
\\ὅπερ ἔδει δεῖξαι \\
θα ειμαι ευγνωμων για οποια βοηθεια προσφερθει.
\end{document}


what did you have before raspberry5/wayland which worked? was that using X11?

In case you don't find a solution for texmaker, maybe give texstudio a try

@cfr I had the raspberry 4 which is X11 I think. It is not readily accessible to me now.  I think Raspberry 5 can handle more load so, in a way, it has its benefits...

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you, I honestly did not think of that.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz unfortunately the problem persists in TexStudio. And by the way, it happens with any keyboard, I tried an ordinary one.

@StefanosRotas Oh, too bad! Sorry it didn't work!

wayland and x11 use different methods to configure inputs. or, at any rate, they can. libinput provides significantly more control of things like pointing devices and keyboards etc. than equivalent methods compatible with wayland. however, if that's the issue, I'd expect it to apply to more than just your tex editor. does texmaker support wayland natively or is it using a compatibility layer? similarly for texstudio. if not, try an editor which is designed for, or has been adapted to, wayland. it could also be that using a different compositor-thingy would help. (can't remember details.)
